# How to convert PDF page to c# Bitmap object (not to file)?

Tags: c#, pdf, bitmap

Is there a way to convert a PDF page to bitmap in c#? I tried with Ghostscript but I think it is file based. Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1):

[LibPdf](https://code.google.com/archive/p/lib-pdf/)

This library converts converts PDF file to an image. Supported image formats are PNG and BMP, but you can easily add more.

```
using (FileStream file = File.OpenRead(@"..\path\to\pdf\file.pdf")) // in file
{
    var bytes = new byte[file.Length];
    file.Read(bytes, 0, bytes.Length);
    using (var pdf = new LibPdf(bytes))
    {
        byte[] pngBytes = pdf.GetImage(0,ImageType.BMP); // image type
        using (var outFile = File.Create(@"..\path\to\pdf\file.bmp")) // out file
        {
            outFile.Write(pngBytes, 0, pngBytes.Length);
        }
    }
}
```

Read this article: [PDF to bmp Images (12 pages = 12 images)](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24653716/pdf-to-bmp-images-12-pages-12-images)

Comment: LibPdf has an issue with dependencies and Bytescout PDF Renderer SDK is not free. Do you have any more suggestion?. Thank you for your time